# how to install FFMpeg in xampp and laravel 9

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp

i have tried

[Install FFMPEG on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977448/install-ffmpeg-on-xampp)

this method to install...

i have no idea about FFMpeg.... please command me the steps from downloading the FFMpeg to install in xampp...

and than to setup in laravel

Comment: **What** have you tried? "It does not works" is a pretty broad description. You haven't shared a single line of code yet

Comment: i have run this command in my controller.....

FFMpeg::fromDisk('videos')
            ->open('steve_howe.mp4')
            ->export()
            ->useSegmentFilenameGenerator(function ($name, $format, $key, callable $segments, callable $playlist) {
                $segments("{$name}-{$format->getKiloBitrate()}-{$key}-%03d.ts");
                $playlist("{$name}-{$format->getKiloBitrate()}-{$key}.m3u8");
            });

and my binary path

C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\textToSpeech2\public\FFMpeg\bin

and

Comment: would you please tell to install FFMpeg in my xampp server from the very begining..... given link in question is already tried

Comment: i have declared the binary path in my .env file too

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Installing FFMpeg is not related to programming itself, and if the installation itself run properly, this looks like a configuration related issue to me (which is not related to programming itself either)

Comment: i made it very clear in question

Comment: "please command me the steps from downloading the FFMpeg to install in xampp" - that's an off-topic request for StackOverflow, especially if you haven't shown what you've tried and where you are stuck